# Find the last value after a search in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have created an excel spreadsheet to track some loans. When I do a search to filter out a period of dates, I want to highlight the last payment value of that search. How do I highlight that number?

I've been looking at various formulas but I'm not sure which one to use

Comment: Please specify how did you do the '**search**'? If possible please provide a sample picture of the original data and an expected result.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not even sure what to look for as I don't know the different formulas that well in excel. I'm just typing in a sentence hoping to find something that leads me somewhere... Most results show me how to tag the last number in the column (eg $128,500) which is fine, but once the table has been filtered through a date search, and the last number changes (eg $129,750), the formula still results in the last original number ($128,500).

Comment: Please upload a screenshot of the original data set or make a sample of the data set, and then upload another screenshot highlight the problems and explain clearly what you expect to see in the result.

Comment: without sample data we are just guessing

Comment: Thanks, I'm tracking a loan and the balance column is the one I'm working with. Use these as an example: Jan = 120000, Feb = 119,500, March = 118000, April = 117000. If I click on Data then Auto-filter, then click on the arrow to filter out only Jan and Feb figures for a statement balance. I want the last figure in the column to read 119,500 but all the formulas I can find leave me with the April figure still even though it isn't part of the search. Hope that helps, Sorry, I'm not able to find where to upload a pic... Cheers

Comment: Please **edit your question** to add details. Don't put details into comments. Nobody wants to trawl through a page of comments to find out what your question *really* is.  There is an icon to include images. As a new user, these images will need to be made visible by a user with more rep. Please post a comment when you have done that, then the followers of this question will be alerted. You may want to read [ask] and take the [tour].